# How do you get the ElasticSearch `refresh_interval` for an index?

Tags: elasticsearch

After reading some Elasticsearch index tuning guides like [How to Maximize Elasticsearch Index Performance](https://qbox.io/blog/maximize-guide-elasticsearch-indexing-performance-part-1?utm_source=qbox.io&utm_medium=article&utm_campaign=maximize-guide-elasticsearch-indexing-performance-part-2) and elastic's [Tune for indexing speed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/tune-for-indexing-speed.html) I wanted to take a look at updating the refresh_interval.

We are using AWS Elasticsearch domains (elasticsearch version 6.2). There's no mention of refresh_interval on Cloudformation's doc site [AWS::Elasticsearch::Domain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticsearch-domain.html)

So I wanted to see what the default setting was for AWS Elasticsearch.
Using the _settings API doesn't show the refresh_interval.

```
GET /my_index/_settings
```

And specifying the refresh_interval doesn't show anything either.

```
GET /my_index/_settings/index.refresh_interval
```

Only returns an empty object.

```
{}
```

How can I find the current refresh_interval for Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add a parameter called `include_defaults` in order to also retrieve the default values:

```
GET /my_index/_settings?include_defaults=true
```

In the response, you'll get a `defaults` section which includes the default value of the `refresh_interval` setting, most probably `1s`.

NOTE: The reason the `refresh_interval` is empty is because your index has not set the value explicitly and so your index uses the default value.